# Getting error while running angular 9 test case using jasmine and karma

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am getting error when I am writing unit test case using jasmine and karma in angular 9.

login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { routerTransition } from "../router.animations";
import { AuthenticationService } from "../_services/authentication.service";
import { NgxSpinnerService } from "ngx-spinner";

@Component({
  selector: "app-login",
  templateUrl: "./login.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./login.component.scss"],
  animations: [routerTransition()],
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  userForm = {
    username: "",
    password: "",
    device_id: "",
  };
  isError: boolean = false;
  constructor(
    public spinner: NgxSpinnerService,
    private _router: Router,
    private Service: AuthenticationService
  ) {}
  ngOnInit() {}
  msg = "";
  onSearchChange(searchValue: string) {
    this.isError = false;
  }
  login() {
    this.isError = false;
    if (!this.userForm.username && !this.userForm.password) {
      this.isError = true;
      this.msg = "Username or password cannot be empty";
      return;
    }
    if (!this.userForm.username) {
      this.isError = true;
      this.msg = "Username cannot be empty";
      return;
    }
    if (!this.userForm.password) {
      this.isError = true;
      this.msg = "Password cannot be empty";
      return;
    }
    this.spinner.show("loader-opdk", {
      type: "timer",
      size: "medium",
      bdColor: "transparent",
      color: "#2e98cf",
      fullScreen: true,
    });
    this.Service.login(this.userForm).subscribe((status) => {
      this.spinner.hide("loader-opdk");
      if (status.responseCode===200) {
        this.isError = false;
        this._router.navigate(["/"]);
      } else {
        this.isError = true;
        this.msg = "Invalid username or password";
      }
    });
  }

  onLoggedin() {
    localStorage.setItem("isLoggedin", "true");
  }
}


app.module.ts

import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from "@angular/common/http";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import { NgxSpinnerModule } from "ngx-spinner";
import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { ToastrModule } from "ngx-toastr";
import { LoginModule } from "./login/login.module";
import { BasicAuthInterceptor, ErrorInterceptor } from "./_helpers";
import { AuthenticationService } from "./_services";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgxSpinnerModule,
    LoginModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: BasicAuthInterceptor, multi: true },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true },
    AuthenticationService,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}



authentication.service.ts

import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from "rxjs";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
import { URLS } from "./URLS";
import { User } from "../_models";

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class AuthenticationService {
  private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<any>;
  public currentUser: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(
      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser"))
    );
    this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
  }

  public get currentUserValue(): any {
    return this.currentUserSubject.value;
  }
  getToken() {
    return localStorage.getItem("token");
  }
  getUserId() {
    return this.currentUserSubject.value.userId;
  }
  login(req) {
    return this.http
      .post<any>(URLS.BASE_PATH + "/auth2/token", {
        userName: req.username,
        userPassword: req.password,
      })
      .pipe(
        map((user) => {
          if (user.responseCode === 200) {
            localStorage.setItem(
              "currentUser",
              JSON.stringify(user.userList[0])
            );
            localStorage.setItem("token", user.token);
            this.currentUserSubject.next(user.userList[0]);
            return user;
          }
          else{
            return user;
          }
        })
      );
  }
  logout() {
    // remove user from local storage to log user out
    localStorage.clear();
    this.currentUserSubject.next(null);
  }
}


login.component.spec.ts

import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AuthenticationService } from "../_services/authentication.service";

import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
import { LoginModule } from './login.module';

fdescribe('LoginComponent', () => {
  let component: LoginComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;
  let authService : AuthenticationService;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [LoginComponent],
      imports: [
        LoginModule,
        RouterTestingModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
      ],
      providers:[AuthenticationService],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    authService = TestBed.get(AuthenticationService); 
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

//   it('needsLogin returns true when the user has not been authenticated', () => {
//     spyOn(authService, 'login').and.returnValue('false');
//     expect(component.login()).toBeTruthy();
//     expect(authService.login).toHaveBeenCalled();
// });

fit('should create', () => {
  expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
});
```

but when running this the test case I am getting below error

Failed: Type LoginComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: LoginModule and DynamicTestModule! Please consider moving LoginComponent to a higher module that imports LoginModule and DynamicTestModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes LoginComponent then import that NgModule in LoginModule and DynamicTestModule.

could you please help me on this.

Comment: Are you sure imported LoginComponent only once?

Comment: @kian....sorry I didn't get you.. LoginComponent only once ?

Comment: The error said you declared LoginComponent in two diffrent module. if you declared that in login module so didn't need to declared again in configureTestingModule.

Comment: @kian..which line should I remove from the configureTestingModule ?

Comment: instead of again importing LoginComponent into DynamicTestModule,
either just import LoginModule into DynamicTestModule or use SharedModule